# UICollectionView inside of a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I gotta to create a `UICollectionView` inside of a `UITabBarController`. I've trying many ways, but I always end up getting an error.

This is my code at the moment:

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UICollectionViewDataSource 
{
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
```

> I got an error in self.collectionView.dataSource = self, which is: **Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**
>           }
>       }

```
//CollectionView
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "idCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .blue

    return cell
}
```

This is how I created the screen:

**TabBarScreenStoryboard**

[image]

**TabBarController**

[image]

[image]

So, what would be the best way for me to do that?

Comment: Why are you adding the methods from `UITableViewDataSource` instead of `UICollectionViewDataSource`?

Comment: Oops, completely my bad. This was effect of stay in front of the computer for many hours. I replaced the code, but I still getting an error, could you check it out, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: Your outlet isn't connected.

Comment: I checked both, but I still getting that message

Comment: How do you create and display an instance of this `TabBarController` class?

Comment: I just updated posting a picture of the storyboard

Comment: I updated once again, now posting a picture of the TabBarController class

Comment: Surely the collection view simply isn't hooked up.

Comment: I added a picture, to make sure it's hooked up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to fix by checking the Storyboard where I had a Sigabart error.